# Is there a single word to define a bag thief?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, synonyms

Searching a meaning of a Japanese word *okibiki*.
I have found a definition:

> walking away with another's bag

But you can call someone a *okibiki*. Analyzing it, the person is a bag thief. Then in English, there is another single word to define it?

If not, is usual to say "bag thief"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only more-or-less common English expressions that come close to it in meaning I can think of are all two words (though they could be hyphenated):

*bag-snatcher*, *purse-snatcher*, and perhaps (if they're only taking a wallet) *wallet-lifter* -- and that one's quite a bit rarer in usage (and *pickpocket* would probably be more common for that case).

There's the archaic *cutpurse*, but that doesn't quite fit.

While "bag-thief" is clear enough, *bag-snatcher* is probably more idiomatic.

Comment: +1 for 'snatcher', we can use it for the things we carry with us. Chain snatcher, for instance.

Comment: "purse-snatcher" is more common in AmE   (since 1940) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purse-snatcher%2C+bag-snatcher&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpurse%20-%20snatcher%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbag%20-%20snatcher%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Brian a purse is more specific than a bag, so even if purse-snatcher were more common that doesn't necessarily make it more apt. It might be a gym bag that was stolen, for example, and in that case, purse-snatcher would be wrong.

Comment: But wrong or not, Americans might call the thief a purse-snatcher. If bags are more commonly grabbed now than they were in 1940, or even equally often, how do you explain the increasing predominance of "purse-snatcher" since 1940 in AmE?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Better not to ask me to explain the choices Americans make. That makes not the slightest sense to me, I appreciate your valuable input though -- it's worth knowing it's more common in American English even when the object isn't a purse (as odd as that might seem to other English-speakers).

Answer (score 0):

A word with a meaning close to what you're looking for does exist, but in my experience it's not used in the literal sense very often:

From [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=cutpurse&allowed_in_frame=0):

> **cutpurse (n.)**
>   "one who steals by the method of cutting purses, a common practice when men wore their purses at their girdles" [Johnson], mid-14c., from cut (v.) + purse (n.). The word continued after the method switched to picking pockets.

**Bag thief** is easily understood, but redundant and not idiomatic in all situations. For instance, you would not say:

> A bag thief stole my pack.

But rather just:

> A thief stole my pack.